# Tomcat 8: CORS filter doesn't work

Tags: tomcat, cors

Here I have an application deployed in Tomcat 8 instance. I have followed [Tomcat 8 document](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) to add CORS filter in :

```
/apache-tomcat-8/conf/Catalina/web.xml
```

with basically the same configuration in the document

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and when I run following command:

```
curl -I "http://localhost:8181/MySuperApp/login/"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C51BD2982C0EBB7DA73D40E7AE856B93; Path=/MySuperApp/; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 883
Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2016 20:20:11 GMT
```

So basically, CORS didn't take effect at all...what could be possible missing, or is there any places I should check that the parameters may be overridden?

Answer (score 1):

The CORS filter will only send back the Access-Control-* headers if the request specified an Origin header. Without an Origin it's not a CORS request.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to enforce the Origin from a request by Tomcat?

Comment: @Dreamer I'm not sure what you mean by "enforce" - if you want to test the CORS filter you have to send a request that has an `Origin` header, e.g. `curl -I -H 'Origin: http://www.example.com' http://localhost:8181/MySuperApp/login/`